# Restoring track information for iTunes Match files

Tags: icloud, windows, itunes-match, itunes

I made the mistake of editing a bunch of songs at once. Now, the changes have propagated to all of my iTunes Match registered devices. I tried `Advanced > Get Track Names`, but I get the following message

> iTunes cannot get CD track names for songs that were not imported using iTunes

[image: get track names]

The thing is, the songs **were** originally imported using iTunes before syncing with iTunes Match.

Is there an easy way to restore track information, or must I manually go through the tracks and fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must fix the track data yourself, however, that doesn't mean that you have to do it manually (but of course you can).

There is a myriad of software that aims to do this for you automatically. One that I can think of off the top of my head for Windows is [TuneUp](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/). It's a bit expensive, $40 for a year or $50 for "Lifetime". It runs along side iTunes and fixes it up when requested, or even automatically if configured.

There is plenty of other software I'm sure, some that aids the process of doing it manually, others that try to do it completely on it's own ala. TuneUp.

Comment: I was going to suggest Pollux and Song Genie as well, but Pollux is no longer available for new users, and Song Genie is OS X-only. Sorry! The windows-only nature of the question caught me...

Comment: I was worried this would be as usual, regardless of iTunes Match. Perhaps in the future, Apple will add a feature to iTunes Match which polls their servers for track information.

Comment: Update: I tried TuneUp Lite and it worked perfectly! Purchasing the lifetime license for only $40, as it is currently discounted. Worth it! Thanks. :)